# plotting graphs with dspPlot functions

Tags: pstricks, plot

I have tried plotting graphs with dspPlot [as explained by Prof. Paolo Prandoni and Prof. Martin Vetterli in their site](http://www.signalprocessingforcommunications.org/readers.html) but failed. They have run the following code to generate curve in their DSP book available online in their site. However, when I run the same, it does not work. Anybody can help me out please. [I wrote to authors few days back and reply is yet to receive from their end]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{dspTricks, dspFunctions, dspBlocks}

\newenvironment{centerfig}{%
  \begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{center}}{
    \end{center}
  \end{figure}}


\begin{document}
\begin{centerfig}
\begin{dspPlot}[sidegap=0.5,yticks=none]{-6, 6}{-1.2, 1.2}
    \def\signal{ 0.5235 mul RadtoDeg sin }
    \def\quantize{ dup 0 gt {-0.5} {0.5} ifelse sub truncate }
    \dspFunc[linecolor=gray,linewidth=2pt]{x \quantize \signal }
    \dspFunc[linestyle=dotted,linewidth=1pt]{x \signal}
    \dspSignal{x \signal}
\end{dspPlot}
\end{centerfig}
\end{document}
```

Program fragment and its output is appended below for your kind reference:

[image]

Error I got after running the code is:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \c@lor@to@ps

l.19 ...sidegap=0.5,yticks=none]{-6, 6}{-1.2, 1.2}

?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

run the document with `xelatex` or the sequence `latex` -> `dvips` -> `ps2pdf` or use the package `auto-pst-pdf`. However, no need to use the package `float`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{dspTricks, dspFunctions, dspBlocks}

\newenvironment{centerfig}
  {\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\centering}
  {\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}

\begin{centerfig}
\begin{dspPlot}[sidegap=0.5,yticks=none]{-6, 6}{-1.2, 1.2}
    \def\signal{ 0.5235 mul RadtoDeg sin }
    \def\quantize{ dup 0 gt {-0.5} {0.5} ifelse sub truncate }
    \dspFunc[linecolor=gray,linewidth=2pt]{x \quantize \signal }
    \dspFunc[linestyle=dotted,linewidth=1pt]{x \signal}
    \dspSignal{x \signal}
\end{dspPlot}

\begin{dspPlot}[xtype=freq,xout=true]{-1,1}{-0.5,1.5}
  \dspFunc[linecolor=gray,linestyle=dashed]{x \dspSincS{0}{6} 13 div}
  \dspFunc{x \dspFIRI{ 0.3501  0.2823  0.1252 -0.0215 -0.0876
     -0.0868    0.0374} }
\end{dspPlot}
\end{centerfig}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Not a direct answer to your question, but here's a way to draw the graph without specialised packages using TikZ instead of PSTricks (so it can be run with any compiler):

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            domain=0:360,
            hide y axis,
            axis x line*=middle,
            xtick=\empty,
            samples=13,
            width=10cm, height=5cm
        ]
    \addplot [const plot mark mid, very thick, gray] {sin(x)};
    \addplot [ycomb, mark=*, thick, mark size=1] {sin(x)};
    \addplot [densely dotted, samples=51] {sin(x)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Should the `samples` be an odd integer?

Comment: @Jake. Thank you for this wonderful answer. I would very much like to use your coding which runs on pdfLaTeX.

Comment: @kissmyarmpit, samples lie on integer values whether odd or even integer. Sorry for the late reply. Sorry, I was excited seeing the answer and forgot to give you a reply.